java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleOwner is attempting to register while current state is RESUMED
When it is that the string has changed, I get exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleOwner ... is attempting to register while current state is RESUMED. LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED.

That exception is thrown on the line:
dropInClient = new DropInClient(DonateActivity.this, clientToken);

private String amount = "";
    private DropInClient dropInClient;
    private DropInRequest dropInRequest = new DropInRequest();
    private MutableLiveData<String> clientTokenValue = new MutableLiveData<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_donate);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        hideActionBar();
        getClientToken();
        setupListeners();

        clientTokenValue.observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(String clientToken) {
                Log.d("LOGTRACETOKEN", "onChanget" + clientToken);
                if (clientToken != null && !clientToken.isEmpty()) {
                    try {
                        dropInClient = new DropInClient(DonateActivity.this, clientToken);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("LOGTRACETOKEN", e.toString());
                    }
                    try {
                        dropInClient.setListener(DonateActivity.this);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("LOGTRACETOKEN", e.toString());
                    }
                    Log.d("LOGTRACETOKEN", clientToken);
                } else {
                    showToast("Failed to fetch client token");
                    Log.e("LOGTRACETOKEN", "Client token is empty");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void getClientToken(){
        try {
            BaseWebserviceAPI apiCall = APIClient.getInstance().getClient(true).create(BaseWebserviceAPI.class);
            Call<Map<String, String>> tokenCall = apiCall.getBtreeClientToken();
            tokenCall.enqueue(new GenericCallback<>(new GenericCallback.CallbackListener<Map<String, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void onDataReceived(Map<String, String> data) {
                    clientTokenValue.setValue(data.get("clientToken"));
                }

                @Override
                public void onRequestFailure() {
                    showToast("Failed to fetch client token");
                }
            }));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("CLIENTTOKENE", e.toString());
        }
    }

I get the same thing if I try to setup drop in client directly when i get the response from the GET request (onDataReceived).

in the DropInClient, are you trying to launch an activity for result?

Yes. the "new DropInClient" is trying to launch "DropInActivity" for the result, but it is launching the activity on the button click:
private void handlePaymentButtonClick(View view) {         if (!isAmountValid()) {             showToast(ERROR_MESSAGE);         } else {             dropInClient.launchDropIn(dropInRequest);         }     }
and there I get Exception due to the previous Exception:
Attempt to invoke virtual method  on a null object reference

can you post the full code of hideActionBar(), getClientToken(), setupListeners(), and DropInClient? the launcher must be registered on activity's onCreate but I don't see it on your code.
